# Gradle ziptree fails on chinese filename

Tags: gradle, internationalization, zip, build.gradle

I have a Zipfile containing a foldername in Chinese.

The Zipfile can be extracted without any problems using Linux unzip, Windows Winrar and 7Zip

When using Gradles "ziptree" I always get the following error:

```
Could not expand ZIP '/pathToZip/myZip.zip'.
```

Stacktrace says:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy zip entry /pathToZip/myZip.zip!somefolderstructure/??/ to '/destination/somefolderstructure/??'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.SyncCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(SyncCopyActionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.maybeVisit(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.access$000(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTreeImpl$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:181)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:91)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.FileException: Could not set file mode 755 on '/destination/somefolderstructure/??'.
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.GenericFileSystem.chmod(GenericFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:76)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not set UNIX mode on /destination/somefolderstructure/??: could not convert string to current locale
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultPosixFiles.setMode(DefaultPosixFiles.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.NativePlatformBackedChmod.chmod(NativePlatformBackedChmod.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.GenericFileSystem.chmod(GenericFileSystem.java:87)
    ... 109 more
```

I already tried to set the File Encoding in gradle.properties

```
file.encoding=utf-8
```

I tried to add a Gradle Parameter

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

I also tried different Gradle Versions: 3.4.1 and 2.14

Nothing works.

**UPDATE**

Here is my build.gradle (paths don't match the stacktrace because I manually modified the stacktrace):

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile).each {
    it.options.encoding = defaultEncoding
}
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).each {
    it.groovyOptions.encoding = defaultEncoding
}

configurations {
    mydependencies
}

dependencies {
    mydependencies 'my.group:my-artifact:1.0.0@zip'
}

task copyArtifact(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.mydependencies
    into "$buildDir/zip"
}

task extractZip(type: Sync) {
    from zipTree("$buildDir/zip/my-artifact.zip")
    into "$buildDir/xtract"
}
```

Any Ideas?

Modifying the zip is the last solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the chinese folder is only for testing-purpose of a node submodule (https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic/tree/master/test/public/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87) I use the "exclude" from my copy task:

```
task extractDependency(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree( configurations.mydependencies )
    into "$buildDir/xtract"
    exclude "$parentFolder/npm/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/ecstatic/test/public/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Your `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is gradle's encoding itself, but it does not affect to compile encoding. Please use this on your `build.gradle`.

```
def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile).each {
  it.options.encoding = defaultEncoding
}
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).each {
  it.groovyOptions.encoding = defaultEncoding
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response :-)
Nevertheless it does not work because I don't need the zip in the Compile but in the Sync task.
I also tried tasks.withType with the following parameters:
Copy, Sync, AbstractCopyTask - makes no difference

Comment: (I delete a comment bacause I did not read updated question.)

Comment: This is not the answer, but might be your help. [Support metadataCharset on Project.zipTree() · Issue #1363 · gradle/gradle · GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1363)